# Java sockets doesn't work on windows

Tags: java, windows, sockets

I'm trying to make an program where I'd like to connect two devices in the same wifi, so I'm trying to use sockets.

I have the server code running on my pc and client side on android device. 
The problem is that the server does not work on windows, but it does on linux.
I disconnected all the firewalls, windows and avast, but I still have the same problem.
I've tried to use a linux machine as server and windows as client and it works perfectly.

I put some prints to see where it stops and the server side in windows is stop when I try to get the Socket "Socket s = ss.accept();". I don't get any error it just gets stuck there.

I don't know what could be wrong.

Server side

```
   int port = 2002;  
   try {  
            ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

            Socket s = ss.accept();

            InputStream is = s.getInputStream();  
            ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(is); 

            System.out.println((String)ois.readObject());  
            is.close();  
            s.close();  
            ss.close();  
   }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
```

Client side:

```
try{  
            String hostPortatil = "192.168.1.131";
            String host = "192.168.174.1";
            int port = 2002;
            Socket s = new Socket(hostPortatil, port);  

            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();

            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);  

            oos.writeObject(new String("another object from the client"));  

            oos.close();  
            os.close();  
            s.close();  
}catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: _"does not work"_? Does it crash? If not, what's happening?

Comment: I am pretty sure Java sockets DO work on windows ;) Did you check you have all the needed permissions in Android?

Comment: are you connecting to the correct port. I see client trying to connect to port 2002, whereas the server listens on 9999. Otherwise i see no errors in that code.

Comment: @Fildor I don't think he's claiming that Java Sockets are broken in windows. He's saying that it's not working in his case and he's confused as to why. But, I agree, that I would be pointing the finger at the client before the server here.

Comment: Hey sorry for the not really good explanation. I made a mistake copying the code, both are connect to the port 2002.  My point is that the same code working with linux as server works, but it doesn't with windows as server. In Windows the code get stuck in the line ss.accept().

Comment: @Cruncher You may have missed the ";)" ... :D

Answer (score 1):

Your server is configure to listen connections on port 9999, but client connects using port 2002

Edit:

Start the server on windows and open a cmd.exe:

```
netstat -an|findstr "2002"
```

you should see your java process listening for connections. If not then something is wrong. In the linux server open a shell:

```
telnet 192.168.1.131 2002
```

You should connect from the linux server to the windows server. Again if not some is wrong.

Comment: My bet would be a mistake on copying code over to SO. I find it hard to believe that this works if you run the server in linux, and client in windows

Comment: I tried it.
from windows cmd I get this:
TCP    0.0.0.0:2002           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
TCP    [::]:2002              [::]:0                 LISTENING

And from linux I guess I have to use telnet with windows machine ip so 192.168.174.1
And I get this:
Trying 192.168.174.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: connection timed out

I tried to disconnect all the firewalls just in case.

Comment: What you get on the windows machine says that the java process is listening correctly and bound to all interfaces, if you can't connect from the linux machine , it is most likely an network/firewall issue. Check again, it is not problem with your code or java runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you have not configured your Windows firewall to accept connections on port 2002.

Comment: I've tried to configured but at the end I decided to close the firewall to see if this is the problem.

Comment: BTW You don't need to wrap a String with a String. You can remove the `new String`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because you are running the server side of your program on Windows which will assign the localhost ip to your sever side and that ip is certainly different from the ip of your local Wi-Fi and hotspot connection. 
I run both client and server side of a sample app on Windows with localhost and worked but didn't worked with ip of my Wi-Fi and hotspot connection on two different platform. 
I guess it would be fixed by turning the computer to a server!

Comment: Can you clarify this answer?  While it's likely that the original author got an answer after nearly 7 years it's not clear what you're trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The accept() method is waiting for a client to establish a TCP connection and that's why there's no output and no error, so the problem seems to be in the client side.